# Как разместить картинки таким образом?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как разместить картинки таким образом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```css
.wrapper-img {
  display: flex;
}

.img-1,
.img-2,
.img-3,
.img-4,
.img-5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.img-2 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.img-3 {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.img-4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.img-5 {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: brown;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-img">
  <div class="img-1"></div>
  <div class="img-2"></div>
  <div class="img-3"></div>
  <div class="img-4"></div>
  <div class="img-5">375+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Надо было задать общий класс всем изображениям и задать ему margin-left: -30px; и :first-child - margin-left: 0; А то расплодили ненужные классы)